# a new representation for Eulerian numbers?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, polynomials, enumerative-combinatorics

The [Eulerian numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number) enjoy many different presentations among which I write the two-variable recursive definition: $A(n,0)=1$ and $A(n,k)=0$ for $k<0$ so that
$$A(n,k)=(k+1)A(n-1,k)+(n-k)A(n-1,k-1).$$
However, my curiosity is regarding a certain "vanishing-variables" formulation (summation) over the symmetry (permutation) groups $\mathfrak{S}_n$:

> **QUESTION.** For $0\leq k\leq n$ and a set of variables $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n+1}$, experiments suggest
>   $$A(n,k)=\sum_{\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_{n+1}}(x_{\pi(1)}+\cdots+x_{\pi(k+1)})^n\prod_{i=1}^n\frac1{x_{\pi(i)}-x_{\pi(i+1)}}.$$
>   It seems correct to me. Proof or disproof? I am still hoping and waiting.

Comment: What is $k$? Should it be $i$?

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a typo. The numerator does not depend on $i$. The $k$ reflects the one on the LHS. I rewrote the RHS so as not to confuse anyone.

Comment: My mistake—sorry.

Comment: Are you sure about the "rt.representation-theory" tag?  That usually refers to linear representations of group, not of the kind of representation you're asking for; it's true that there's a lot of combinatorics bound up in the representation theory of the symmetric group, but as it stands that combinatorics is not visible here.

Comment: I've seen formulas like this around Postnikov and Chapoton, in the context of polytopes. But that doesn't directly translate to anything useful so far :)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: I understand your reason. I've some hope that someone might have an idea from a different angle (say from Rep. Theory, as it not uncommon). In the present case, even some Schubert calculus will not surprise me either. I've seen wonderful formula drop out from Gauge Theory into Combinatorics, etc. So, let's not close the door.

Comment: The Postnikov connection is most visible in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507163v1 , which has both symmetrization formulas and Eulerian numbers (not sure if together).

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I was aware of this seminal paper. The treatment in Section 3 is symmetrization as in here and the approach and calculations in Section 9 (referring to "Eulerians") are different. I don't see how one reveals the other, in a transparent way.

Comment: Shouldn't Theorem 3.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507163v1 (applied to $n = n+1$ and $x_i = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{ if } i \leq k+1; \\ 0, & \text{ if } i > k+1 \end{cases}$) reveal that your right hand side is $n! \operatorname{Vol} P_{n+1}\left(\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{k+1 \text{ entries}}, \underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{n-k \text{ entries}}\right) = n! \operatorname{Vol} \Delta_{k+1,n+1}$ ? And identifying this with the left hand side is the classical geometric interpretation of Eulerian numbers?

Comment: This said, I'd still welcome a combinatorial/algebraic proof!

Comment: One can show that this expression is actually an integer. To see that, it suffices to show that after multiplication by $\prod_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)$ this becomes a polynomial divisible by all the factors $x_i-x_j$, i.e., vanishing when $x_i=x_j$; whis is easily seen. After that, it suffices to check the formula for some appropriately hosen collection of values of the $x_i$.

Comment: Hm. If I were asked by any other person, I would immediately say that this is proved in your Proceedings paper on symmetrization.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: You're almost right. Lemma 20 (proved) and Problem 1 (proof not included) are two variants in the online version of the paper. The one in this post is different in formulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quiet a short algebraic proof may go as follows (I cite my own [manuscript](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07136)). For a polynomial $f(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})$ of degree at most $n$ we define a linear operator $$\Phi[f]=\text{Sym}\, \frac{f(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})}{(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)\dots (x_n-x_{n+1})},$$
where $\text{Sym}\, g(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})=\sum g(x_{\pi_1},\dots,x_{\pi_{n+1}})$, the summation is over all $(n+1)!$ permutations of the variables. Note that $\Phi[f]$ is actually a polynomial of degree at most 0 (all factors in the denominator are cancelled, see Ilya's comment), in other words, it is a scalar, and the linear operator $\Phi$ is a linear functional.

Several observations about $\Phi$.

1) If $f$ is divisible by $y:=x_1+\dots+x_{n+1}$, then $\Phi[f]=y\Phi[f/y]=0$. (The same holds for any symmetric factor $y$.)

2) Assume that $f=(x_{k}-x_{k+1})h(x_1,\dots,x_k)g(x_{k+1},\dots,x_{n+1})$. Then $$\Phi[f]=\begin{cases}\binom{n+1}k\Phi_k[h]\Phi_{n+1-k}[g],\,\text{if}\deg h=k-1\,\text{and} \deg g=n-k\\
0,\,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

3) If $f$ is divisible by $(x_1+\dots+x_k)(x_{k}-x_{k+1})$, then $\Phi[f]=0$. Indeed, it suffices to consider the polynomials $f=(x_1+\dots+x_k)(x_{k+1}-x_k)h(x_1,\dots,x_k)g(x_{k+1},\dots,x_{n+1})$. For them the claim follows from 1) and 2).

Before proving your Euler numbers claim we prove that $c_k:=\Phi[x_k^n]=(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k-1}$. Induction in $n$. Base is straightforward. Induction step. We have $c_0+\dots+c_n=\Phi(x_1^n+\dots+x_{n+1}^n)=0$, by observation in 1). Next, 
$$
c_k-c_{k+1}=\Phi((x_k-x_{k+1})(x_k^{n-1}+\dots+x_{k+1}^{n-1})=
(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n+1}k 
$$
by 2) and by the induction assumption. We obtain $n+1$ linear relations on $c_1,\dots,c_{n+1}$ which determine 
them uniquely and also the numbers $c_i=(-1)^{i-1}\binom{n}{i-1}$ satisfy these relations. This finishes the induction step.

Now we want to calculate $\Phi[(x_1+\dots+x_{k+1})^n]$. By 3) we have
$$
\Phi[(x_1+\dots+x_{k+1})^n-(x_1+\dots+x_{k}+x_k)^n+x_k^n-x_{k+1}^n]=0,
$$
thus $$\Phi[(x_1+\dots+x_{k+1})^n-(x_1+\dots+x_{k}+x_k)^n]=(-1)^{k}\binom{n+1}k.$$
Next, $$\Phi[(x_1+\dots+x_{k-1}+2x_k)^n-(x_1+\dots+x_{k-2}+3x_{k-1})^n]=(-1)^{k-1}2^n\binom{n+1}{k-1}.$$
Proceeding in this way and summing up we get the standard formula for Eulerian number [(1) on this MathWorld page.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianNumber.html)